# Getting object name using object ID

Tags: salesforce

My requirement is how to get the object name using Object ID. First 3 places of the record Id depends on Object name. Is there any method to getting the Object name to pass the record Id...?? If anyone knows update.

Answer (score 1):

Use [id methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_id.htm)

```
Id tID = 'a0CE0000003FEKcMAO';
System.debug(tID.getSObjectType());
```

Debug:

```
DEBUG|CustomObject__c
```